# What is the alternative for requestTimeout for Sequelize version 6.13.4?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

```
 "dialectOptions": {
      "requestTimeout": 30000      
 }
```

As I know this code works for Sequelize version 4.42.0. Is there any alternative for the version 6.13.4? This is invalid config point as I get the following message "Ignoring invalid configuration option passed to Connection: requestTimeout. This is currently a warning, but in future versions of MySQL2, an error will be thrown if you pass an invalid configuration options to a Connection".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"dialectOptions": {
"connectTimeout":30000
}

Comment: OK, now I am not getting the warning. And also may you know is there a minimum limit for the value of connectTimeout? This is for testing puposes.